# Как сделать, чтобы <asp:Panel> был виден при условии?

Tags: html, c#, visual-studio, asp.net

Есть `.aspx` страничка. В файле есть поля(`textbox`) по посреднику.
Надо поля отображалась только если по пользователю есть настройка(значение) «Разрешить выбирать посредника.
В БД есть таблица `employees`, у колонки `HasChooseBroker` тип `bit` :

```
| ID | [domain_username] | [HasChooseBroker] |
+----+-------------------+-------------------+
| 1  | Mark              |  0                |
| 2  | Alex              |  1                |
```

Есть процедура(получает значение):

```
USE [Fstp]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get_Employee_HasChooseBroker]
    @domain_user_name nvarchar(50),
    @HasChooseBroker bit out
AS
BEGIN
    Select @HasChooseBroker=HasChooseBroker
    from employees
    where domain_username=@domain_user_name
END
```

В коде  вызываю tableAdapter:

```
EmployeesTableAdapters.QueriesTableAdapter qta = new EmployeesTableAdapters.QueriesTableAdapter();
                bool? ok=false;
                qta.Get_Employee_HasChooseBroker(Page.User.Identity.Name, ref ok);
```

Правильно ли код? В `html` создам `asp:Panel` `Visible` внутри него как написать?

Comment: Оценить правильность кода сложно. Явных ошибок не вижу. Внутри asp:Panel создаете контролы, заполняете их. С помощью Visible регулируете видит ли пользователь эти контролы или нет.

Comment: @rogueCapella, создал панельку, в коде дописал    Pnl_Broker.Visible = (bool)ok; работает